# DbUp not appearing in menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, dbup

I have installed DbUp for VS2022. I can see that it is installed when I go to Extensions/Manage Extensions (circle green tick icon)
But when I go to the solution and do Add the Add DbUp does not appear on the sub menu. What is going on?

I've tried logging closing VS2022 to complete the Extension installation.
I tried reinstalling the extension - it says it's already installed.